# How big is too big for the heap

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

My program is in C and I'm compiling with gcc. I'm reading in a file, and storing the contents of the file into a buffer. To do that I need the buffer to be as large as the file. I'm using malloc() to allocate memory for the buffer. Unfortunately, I ran into a file that's 277MB. Is that too much for the heap? I'm getting a seg fault at run time, but no more information than that. It's worked for files as large as 160 MB, but this single outlier of a 277MB file is breaking it.

EDIT: valgrind gives me

@0xC0000022L valgrind gives me

```
==6380== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x8851028, 0x190e6102) (undefined)
==6380== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x8851028, 0x190e6028) (defined)
==6380== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x190e7028, 0x2997c108) (undefined)
==6380== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x190e7028, 0x2997c028) (defined)
==6380== Warning: silly arg (-1737565464) to malloc()
==6380== Invalid write of size 4
==6380==    at 0x8048A49: main (newanalyze.c:85)
==6380==  Address 0x4a00 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6380==
==6380==
==6380== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6380==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4A00
==6380==    at 0x8048A49: main (newanalyze.c:85)
```

but at line 85 is just a small variable that shouldn't be affected by the size of the file.

Comment: What would be helpful is "strace <your program>" and the OS information. The size isn't too big for a modern heap, and I'm pretty sure malloc on linux with stock GCC allocates the space easily.

Comment: Check the return value of `malloc`. A correct program may run out of memory, but it would never segfault.

Comment: Why not use `mmap` for such cases? Also, to get a quick to-the-point analysis run the program under Valgrind (the debug build)

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?y667x54elblca0a

that's the strace info. here's the OS info from uname

Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-26-generic-pae #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 16:45:14 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: i think allocate the entire file in memory is no good if you can do by parts

Comment: Thanks for the strace! Digesting those last 3 lines.

Comment: Well, you could use gdb to check if the seg fault is because of something else that breaks.

Comment: @0xC0000022L libc `malloc` promotes large allocation requests to `mmap` calls internally.

Comment: Yes, it would depend on the implementation though. My point is, however, that `mmap` already provides the means to get a "pointer" to file contents. So why take the way around that?

Comment: @0xC0000022L Sorry, I read the question too quickly and missed the fact that he was mapping a file into memory. You are right.

Comment: "Warning: silly arg (-1737565464) to malloc()" seems like a giveaway. You've called malloc with a value you should not. Possibly your calculation got mixed up in a signed/unsigned aritmetic overflow, or you're doing something else silly. Track down this malloc call, show us the calculation _and all_ the types involved for that call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't give you a solid "why," but mmap2, which appearas to be what malloc is calling on your system, simply reports it's out of memory. Malloc will, in this case, return NULL cause a segfault.

```
munmap(0xb7706000, 4096)                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 2557403136, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1  ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
```

As a counter example, I have a toy program that succeeds with:

```
mmap(NULL, 283652096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2d00994000
```

I would check the memory available on the system or that the program is using. Maybe it's leaking memory badly?

Comment: The trouble is that the program can't allocate enough memory to even start doing things, so it can't really leak. But I do get a null pointer returned from malloc when trying to allocate a space for a very large struct, but not the buffer. The odd thing is that I think the struct should be 36 times the size of the buffer, but that means it should fail on a 160MB file, because I only have 4GB of RAM period.

Comment: Actually it would depend on the resource limits imposed by the sysadmin and the shell invoking the command as well (`ulimit -a`). Also, given your address is already well into the address range beyond 32bit while the addresses on the OP's question are all inside the 32bit range, there you have an important difference.

Comment: Actually, that makes sense as an amount of memory in that mmap2 function, because after a bit of recalculation the struct is a little less than 10 times the size of the buffer. but still, my system info says I have 5.8 GiB of memory, which I guess I'm mistaken and have 6GB of RAM. so I don't know why 2.5GB of memory allocation gets it.

Comment: `core file size     (blocks, -c) 0
    data seg size      (kbytes, -d) unlimited
    file size          (blocks, -f) unlimited
    pending signals            (-i) 47541
    max locked memory  (kbytes, -l) 64
    max memory size    (kbytes, -m) unlimited
    open files                 (-n) 1024
    pipe size       (512 bytes, -p) 8
    POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) 819200
    real-time priority         (-r) 0
    stack size         (kbytes, -s) 8192
    cpu time          (seconds, -t) unlimited
    max user processes         (-u) 47541
    virtual memory     (kbytes, -v) unlimited`

Comment: This answer told me how big the thing was that was messing everything up, and taught me about strace. It ended up being trouble with a super large struct that couldn't be changed much. Luckily, I had just mistakenly made two arrays larger than I actually needed, so changed them and it reduced the size of the struct by a little less than half.

Answer (score 4):

Please pay attention to the output from Valgrind,

> ==6380== Warning: silly arg (-1737565464) to malloc()

-1737565464 is a signed int value, while it is 2557401832 (>2G) if it is taken as a unsigned int. You are passing a >2G parameter to the malloc instead of 277M.

And from the following information, we know that you are trying to write to the address 0x4a00 which is an invalid address, you would expect a SEGV in this scenario. Please check newanalyze.c:85 in your code to see what is it there.

> ==6380== Invalid write of size 4
>
> ==6380==    at 0x8048A49: main (newanalyze.c:85)
>
> ==6380==  Address 0x4a00 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Answer (score 1):

Following up one of the comments, here's how you'd open a file using [mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).  This is assuming you're on a unix.

```
int fd;
struct stat S;
const char* file_base;

if ((fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file %s to read\n", filename);
    return NULL;
}
if (fstat(fd, &S) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't stat file %s!\n", filename);
    close(fd);
    return NULL;
}
if ((file_base = mmap(NULL, S.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE|MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to map file %s\n", filename);
    close(fd);
    return NULL;
}
```

After this, `file_base` points to a bit of memory which contains the entire contents of the file.

The advantages of this way are:

- It takes up essentially no memory (sort-of).  What's actually happening here is that you're making the file the swap space for a bit of memory.
- It takes no time (sort-of).  The bit of newly-identified memory starts off swapped-out, so that when the memory is accessed, all that has to happen is that that bit of file is swapped in, which happens as quickly as it would if this were dynamically allocated with [malloc(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).

This has the bit of memory marked read-only; you can also do this trick with the file read-write, though that means that if you write to the memory you'll simultaneously change the file.

If you're not on a unix, there might still be a `mmap` function available to you.  If not, there'll be some windows-native way of doing the same thing (`CreateFileMapping`).

Comment: Excellent and concise explanation of memory mapped files. Spared me writing up my answer, which I had just started. Added a link to the man page to your answer. +1

Comment: This answer taught me something new, but it ended up not being the thing I needed to do. I would give it a +1 if I could, but I need more reputation.